# Extend string between strings

Tags: regex, notepad++

```
startABCend
->
startABC123end
```

I seek to capture text between `start` and `end`, and extend it, as shown. I tried:

- `find = start.*end`, `replace = \1 123`: will capture `start` and `end` and between, but replace them all
- `find = (?s)(?<=start).+?(?=end)`, `replace = \1 123`: will keep `start` and `end` but replace captured

How to accomplish this with regex in N++?

---

The exact use case is

```
func_name(a, b=1) -> func_name(a, b=1, c=2)
# can also be
func_name(g=5, k=7) -> func_name(g=5, k=7, c=2)
# so capture between `func_name(` and `)` and extend with `, c=2`
```

Comment: [`find = (?s)(?<=start)(.+?)(?=end)`, `replace = \1 123`](https://regex101.com/r/UKzpAe/1/) should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example target does not include the white space you have in your replace string. To accomplish using the group AND append numbers you can use brackets.

Basically:

```
Find: (?<=start)(.+?)(?=end)
Replace: (\1)123

or just

Find: start(.+?)end
Replace: start(\1)123end
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do this without capture groups, and match what you want to replace.

```
\bstart\K.*?(?=end\b)
```

The pattern matches:

- `\bstart` Match `start` preceded by a word boundary
- `\K` Forget what is matched until now
- `.*?` Match as least chars as possible
- `(?=end\b)` Positive  lookahead, assert `end` to the right followed by a word boundary

In the replacement use the full match followed by 123

```
$&123
```

[image]

---

For the updated example data, you could match the format of `key` with an optional `=value`, and optionally repeat that asserting a `)` to the right.

```
\bfunc_name\([^\s,=]+(?:=[^\s,=]+)?(?:,\h*[^\s,=]+(?:=[^\s,=]+)?)*(?=\))
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/PXDk0z/1)

And replace with

```
$&, c=2
```

[image]

Comment: +1, but I couldn't adapt it to my exact use case: `func_name(a, b=1)` --> `func_name(a, b=1, c=2)`. Can it be adjusted to?

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon Those are different string formats. I have added another pattern for those to the answer.